# Error in AWS codepipeline when deploying ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I've created a pipeline which does the following:

1. Git changes trigger next action (code build)
2. Codebuild initiates & builds a docker image from git source
3. Set latest docker container up on Elasticbeanstalk

The first 2 steps are working fine, git changes initiate a codebuild, the codebuild builds a docker image, and then tries to set it up on Elasticbeanstalk (which fails). The following error is thrown:

> Invalid action configuration The action failed because either the
>   artifact or the Amazon S3 bucket could not be found. Name of artifact
>   bucket: MY_BUCKET_NAME. Verify that this bucket
>   exists. If it exists, check the life cycle policy, then try releasing
>   a change.

In my codebuild project, I've set the artifact location to MY_BUCKET_NAME & named it aws-test-artifact. Is this all I have to do?

I've tried looking around and am unable to find anything on this issue.

Answer (score 7):

As Adam Loving commented we must add artifacts section.

Adding this section to your `buildspec.yml` file will make this work.

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

From documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.artifacts.files  adding `'**/*'` will include all files into the build target.

Answer (score 2):

So I found the fix to this issue! What I had to do was goto **codebuild** => **edit project** => **Show advanced settings** => **Artifacts packaging**

From here I changed **Artifacts packaging** to **Zip**!

[image: Advanced settings section]

Comment: There is no option for artifacts packaging

Comment: Also, make sure your Buildspec has an `artifacts` section. Otherwise the build will succeed and link to an artifacts file that doesn't exist and was never uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Just changed Input artifacts from BuildArtifact to SourceArtifact in the build stage, and everything worked.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: This does will exclude any changes to the artifact done during the build step.